# Insertar Datos a Firebase desde php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, firebase

Buenas Colegas quiero insertar datos desde un pequeño programa en PHP a la Base de Datos de Firebase, por medio de Curl, actualmente tengo este código

```
$url = "https://direcciones-.firebaseio.com/hola.json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id:6");
$jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Pero a la hora de Correrlo me la variable $jsonResponse me da 0, y me ingresa a la validacion del error

Cual creen ustedes que pueda ser el problema, ya trate incluso de mandar el archivo JSON completo creandolo con el Json_encode, pero obtengo el mismo problema.

Saludos.

Comment: si vas a enviarlo directamente deberias leer como hacerlo desde la api de google,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data?hl=es-419

Comment: si lo único que quieres hacer es insertar los datos, te recomiendo la forma Json utilizando nada mas el apikey que te brinda firebase, yo he insertado algunos datos y si gustas te paso el dato.

Comment: Diego Azpeitia, eso es exactamento lo que necesito, te agradeceria si me los envias a mi correo ajcg199519@gmail.com

Saludos

Comment: te hice unas impresiones de pantalla de un proyecto que yo tengo, te las agrego... por orden de imagenes:
-obtienes el sdk que firebase te proporciona.
-haces tu formulario con tus id (o no se que tipo de informacion vayas a obtener).
-mediante el id obtienes los valores que vas a asignar a tus variables con el nombre que van a quedar en la "tabla" ya dentro de firebase.
-y mediante una referencia similar a: var referencia=database.ref("eventos"); en firebase se agregaria la "tabla" con el nombre eventos.

Comment: es importante que la seguridad de tu proyecto en firebase esté configurada para que puedas escribir sobre el proyecto.

pd: ya te mandé el correo.

Comment: Tengo el mismo inconveniente, Diego Azpeitia o AndreyC1995, ¿Pueden ayudarme?
Correo: j-esteban1995@hotmail.com

Answer (score -1):

```
$data='{"id":"6"}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: Considera dar una explicación del por qué tu respuesta es válida.